# Modelling a nullable foreign key Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-designer

Take the following pseudocode database

```
table Foo
{
    FooID int not null,
    name varchar not null
}

table Bar
{
    BarID int not null,
    name varchar not null
}

table Waa
{
    WaaID int not null,
    name varchar not null
}

table Link
{
    LinkID int not null,
    FooID int null,
    BarID int null,
    WaaID int null,
    Description varchar not null
}
```

The purpose of the Link table is to allow me to link entities together in a single table, without having multiple `Foo_Bar_Link`, `Foo_Waa_Link` etc. tables.

I am moddeling this DB in EntityFramework v5. As such, i want to be able to specify a One to Many relationship between `Foo` and `Link`, so that i can get all the Links associated with a given Foo.

**Problem**
EntityFramework Designer only lets one-many relationships exist where the foreign key is not null. I want a Foo to have a navigation property `Associations` which gets all of the `Association` entities with `FooID = Foo.FooID`. As a note, i am using the Designer.

Comment: Can you show your Link model? You might also want to see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189701/how-to-get-entity-framework-code-first-and-nullable-foreign-key-properties-to-wov)

Comment: I am creating the whole thing using the EF Designer, so i am not cutting my own model code. I can paste it if required...

Comment: See https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/ - "One Ring to rule them all and in the darkness bind them"

Comment: Actually Colin, What he is talking about is a table which has no explicit relationship. In this case it would be the equivalent of having a `Generic` table with `Table` and `Column` values (for example `"Foo": 1`, `"Bar":2`), so that one can lazily join the tables using `WHERE Table = 'Foo' and Value = 1` which is horribly bad practice.
The table design is explicit (This foo is related to This Bar)

Comment: I tried the designer to start with and found it too limiting. I soon switched to code-first and haven't looked back since. In code-first nullable foreign keys are modelled using nullable properties in the Model class. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF is not designed to support unusual models like yours. The only way which I know is to insert "empty" meaning rows for example with id equals to `-1`. In business logics or in DTO implement "clever" getter and setter.

Comment: Upvote for working answer. Will wait to see if there is some strange setting somewhere that can be changed before marking as answer